# I would like to display sharepoint 2007 list columns vertically, could you please help me?

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2007: WorkRequest List: has n number of columns

I want to display WorkRequest List columns vertically in SharePoint environment, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listViewWebPart` and then convert it to `DataFormWebPart` using SharePoint designer. Once its DataForm , you can customize its XSLT to display columns vertically.

See
http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=150

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your view, there's a section 'Style' that you can expand. Selecting 'Preview Pane' as the style gives you a view with a left column showing the title and a right column displaying the other columns (vertically) of the hovered item.

I don't know if this is exactly what you need, but it's very easy to configure and doesn't need any modifications with SharePoint Designer, so you may want to take a look at it.